# Change On Demand Billing option to 1 Yr Reserved

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I migrated my website over AWS and the billing option I selected for EC2 was 'On Demand', Now Its been around 30 days and I want to change 'On Demand' to '1 Yr Reserved billing option'.
So how Can I do it?
Would appreciate if anyone can help me at earliest.

Comment: First this is not a programming question. Second, a reserved instance is merely a billing method, you just purchase the reserved instance identical to your EC2.  AWS will automatically apply this pricing on your current  on-demand instance.   This is an automatic universal billing offset, you don't need to explicitly on which instance you want to apply the billing.

Comment: @mootmoot Seems like a approach, Will proceed and let you know.

Comment: @mootmoot After purchasing reserved instance, How much time AWS would take  to apply it on current 'On Demand' instance.

Comment: And make sure you are in the correct region when you purchase reserved instance.   Just another fact : because it is a universal billing,  so say if you want to deploy to a new OS version,  you can simply create an identical new on-demand instance with new OS, migrate data from the old instance to the new instance,  then you can shutdown your old instance.  The reserved instance pricing will "automatically" apply to your new instance since it is identical.  AWS will only charge extra upon the "extra" on-demand instance time you use that is not within the reserved instance pricing scope.

Comment: Reserved instance pricing will automatically kick in as soon as the payment is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using the AWS Management Console**

Log in to the AWS Management Console.

1-In the Amazon Web Services menu choose “EC2”.

2-In the left navigation pane, choose “Reserved Instances”.

3-Choose “Purchase Reserved Instances”.

4-Select your Reserved Instance type, platform, payment option, instance type, offering class, and term length. Optionally, check the "Only show offerings that reserve capacity" box to select an Availability Zone, if you want to reserve capacity.

5-Adjust the quantity of instances to purchase and ensure you are comfortable with the price quoted.

6-Confirm your purchase.

For more information read the following doc on the AWS website:

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/reserved-instances/buyer/

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/reserved-instances/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/apply_ri.html

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. The steps you suggested are for purchasing a reserved instance but in my case I want to change billing option of the same on demand instance which I am using currently, Is that possible?

Comment: @AndroidDev , checkout my comment on your question.

Comment: That steps are correct, when you purchase Reserved Instances, AWS calculate your cost base on your purchased reserved instance. For example, when you have an EC2 T2 on demand, AWS calculate the price like on-demand prices, when you are buying EC2 T2 reserved instance, AWS calculate your cost as reserved instance instead of on demand.

Answer (score 0):

Reserved instances are not "attached" to a specific resource, but they are a quota you're purchasing to cover for instances in specific region/AZ, type, size and platform.

Check the usage amount of your instances and base your purchase on what you use. Make sure to purchase RIs only to instances that are 24/7 online... Also try moving your workload to spot instances (where applicable) if the goal is to save money on AWS.

Answer (score -1):

I think u can create at ami with your current ec2, create another ec2 with reserved instance option. Then terminate the current one.

Comment: Reserved instances are not attached to specific instance. It's a quota based on region/AZ, type, size etc.